# How do make Print() a Dataframe

Tags: python

```
with open("Q3.csv", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
rows = csv.reader(csvfile)
for row in rows:
    sentence = row[0]
    analysis = TextBlob(sentence)
    Sentiment3 = analysis.sentiment
    print(Sentiment3)
```

Right now outputs:

```
Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)
Sentiment(polarity=0.475, subjectivity=0.625)
Sentiment(polarity=0.2, subjectivity=0.2)
Sentiment(polarity=0.16, subjectivity=0.5399999999999999)
Sentiment(polarity=0.3, subjectivity=0.6)
Sentiment(polarity=0.1162962962962963, subjectivity=0.425925925925926)
Sentiment(polarity=0.16, subjectivity=0.5399999999999999)
Sentiment(polarity=0.6, subjectivity=0.3962962962962963)
Sentiment(polarity=0.44999999999999996, subjectivity=0.45000000000000007)
Sentiment(polarity=0.3602666666666666, subjectivity=0.7950666666666667)
Sentiment(polarity=0.325, subjectivity=0.625)
Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)
Sentiment(polarity=0.4302083333333333, subjectivity=0.6760416666666667)
etc
```

How do I get this output into a dataframe so it looks like:

```
0 Sentiment(polarity=x, subjectivity=y)
1 Sentiment(polarity=x, subjectivity=y)
2 Sentiment(polarity=x, subjectivity=y)
3 Sentiment(polarity=x, subjectivity=y)
4 Sentiment(polarity=x, subjectivity=y)
etc
```

Let me know if I'm not making sense. It's my first dip into coding.

Comment: You want to have the index along with the sentiment?

Comment: Function "enumerate" can help here.

Answer (score 0):

I made my print output into a list and then set it into a dataframe. It's probably not the most straightforward way:

```
myList=[]
with open("Q3.csv", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
    rows = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in rows:
        sentence = row[0]
        analysis = TextBlob(sentence)
        Sentiment3 = analysis.sentiment
        #print(Sentiment3)
        myList.append(Sentiment3)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(myList)
print(df2)
```